# How to get the date of Git repository init?

Tags: git, datetime

Can I get the date/time of `git init`?

Not the first commit.

If possible, how can I get it?

---

I am looking for this mainly for revision number in continuous integration. 
I like to use Git commit hash for version key, but it's an iOS app, and there's some limitation that I have to use only numbers and commas in version string.

Next, I tried to use Unix timestamp (seconds) as a revision number, but it's too large to show some meaningful information for my project. And then, I got another idea that counting seconds since the current Git repository created.

My current idea is,

```
HEAD_TIMESTAMP=`git show -s --format=%ct HEAD`
INIT_TIMESTAMP=<get init date>
DELTA=`expr $HEAD_TIMESTAMP - $INIT_TIMESTAMP `
DAYS=`expr $DELTA / 86400`
SECS=`expr $DELTA % 86400`
REV=$DAYS.$SECS
```

I think it's also possible to use date/time of first commit. But I like to use date/time of `git init` if it's possible because it's the true creation time of the repository.

Comment: As far as I know, Git doesn't record the timestamp when `git init` was run... if it was ever run at all; what if the repo in question was cloned instead of initialized? However, your best bet might be to get the timestamp of the `.git/description` file. That's one file that gets created during `git init` and that you may not have changed since.

Comment: As a revision number for continuous integration you can just count up continuously, or use the git commit hash, or date plus git commit hash. Relying on clocks and time of several machines will go wrong at some point. You can also count the number of commits, but if you build more than one branch this collides too.

Comment: As mentioned by @Jubobs, this is not generally recorded by `git`. However, as a not-completely-reliable workaround, there are a couple of files/directories within the `.git` directory (like `description`, `branches`, `info` and `hooks`) that may still have the original time stamps from when `git init` was run...

Answer (score 1):

You can find creation date of `.git` directory:
`stat -c %i .git` will give you some number
than run `sudo debugfs -R 'stat <your_number>' /dev/sdXY` and look at `crtime:`

Comment: That's not reliable. The date at which the `.git` folder was created doesn't necessarily correspond to the date at which `git init` was run. Consider the case where you copy your project directory and paste it somewhere else.

Comment: @jthill If an inode's `ctime` contained the creation time, which seems to be a very common misconception, that might be true. However `ctime` stands for "time of last status change", which may be updated for various other events than simply creation - things like changing the owner, group, link count (think adding or removing files in the directory in this case), mode, etc...

Comment: @twalberg well, it's less common by at least one, now :-P ... thanks.